# where should I found etag of rss feed

Tags: python-3.x

Now I want to only get the change of rss feed and not fetch repeat conent, I found the doc from https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/http-etag.html and tell me send a etag to server. but I do not found any etag from rss feed response, and last modified also not found, where to found the etag and last modified? this is the rss address:'https://blog.izgq.net/feed/'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now you are using http request and set timeout, so find the etag from http response:

```
resp = requests.get(source.sub_url, headers=headers, timeout=15.0)
            if resp.status_code == 304:
                logger.info("RSS source not changed")
                return
            # Put it to memory stream object universal feedparser
            content = BytesIO(resp.content)
            if resp.headers.keys().__contains__("Etag"):
                etag = resp.headers['Etag']
            if resp.headers.keys().__contains__("Last-Modified"):
                last_modified = resp.headers['Last-Modified']
```